# Android Emulator device offline

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I am trying to get an application working on an Android emulator. I am using Windows and Android Studio 1.5. When I try to run my application on an emulated device, the device fails to start (it reports as offline) - this is not just a slow startup, as it stays this way for hours.

I have tried every technique I can find, including:
1. Running in admin mode
2. Killing adb and restarting it
3. Restarting the computer, to make sure I have no other devices running.
4. checking the firewall, making sure that everything is allowed through (there are not indications of blocked calls).
5.Recreating the AVD.

Probably others I have forgotten about. No matter what I do, I cannot identify why this device refuses to be online. I can't plug in a device because a) I don't have a pure android phone and b) Sophos does not permit a device to be added. While the laptop I am running on is a corporate on,e I am connecting to the network through my phone, so there are no problems of a corporate firewall blocking this.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. I am not primarily an android developer, but I can try anything suggested.

Comment: try to create new Emulator

Comment: try to use "genymotion" emulator is faster https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: Tried a new emulator. I need to get this working in this environment - I really don't need to get set up in something else.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, I have updated everything (Android Studio 2) and the associates SDK updates, and now it works. Now why couldn't it tell me the problem before? There was no indication of a version discrepancy.